# Deploy to a particular subdomain. using command line firebase hosting or specifying a json to use

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

i have a dev and prod environmnent on firebase hosting with some subdomain.

My CI/CD on gitlab works ok for deploying on dev and prod depending on which branch is merge (dev for dev env or master for prod)

I use this in gitlab CI :

```
script:
    - npm install -g firebase-tools
    - yarn
    - yarn build-dev
    - firebase use env-dev --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
    - firebase deploy -m "Pipe $CI_PIPELINE_ID Build $CI_BUILD_ID" --only hosting --non-interactive --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
```

For prod i just need to change to use env-prod and it will deployed to the main domain without issue

Now for subdomain, they need to be precised in firebase.json with :

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "site": "myproject-dashboard-prod", // can be also myproject-dashboard-dev for dev env
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My question is, where is the hsoting API reference on google website ? I struggle to find it
Because i hope there is a way stipulate directly into the firebase command, my idea would be like this if google allow it :

```
 - firebase deploy -m "Pipe $CI_PIPELINE_ID Build $CI_BUILD_ID" --only hosting --non-interactive --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN --site myproject-dashboard-dev
```

This would solve my issue to deploy from automatize CI/CD, otherwise i don't know how to make the site dynamic in the json object (module.export doesn't work in that case, as it's not imported but read directly by firebase command) or maybe there is a way to precise which json should be used by firebase command and i can make 2 of them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, found out you can actually use array inside firebase.json and target which settings should be used in command line, so you can deploy to 2 env on a subdomain like this :

-firebase.json :

```json
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "site": "mydomain-subdomain-prod",
      "public": "dist",
      "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "site": "mydomain-subdomain-dev",
      "public": "dist",
      "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

-.gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
dev:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - dev
  script:
    - npm install -g firebase-tools
    - yarn
    - yarn build-dev
    - firebase use mydomain-dev --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
    - firebase deploy -m "Pipe $CI_PIPELINE_ID Build $CI_BUILD_ID" --only hosting:mydomain-subdomain-dev --non-interactive --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN

prod:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - npm install -g firebase-tools
    - yarn
    - yarn build-prod
    - firebase use mydomain-prod --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
    - firebase deploy -m "Pipe $CI_PIPELINE_ID Build $CI_BUILD_ID" --only hosting:mydomain-subdomain-prod --non-interactive --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
```

Here is the associated [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites)

It look like site and target are the same thing, if a firebase member can explain if there is a difference between the two ?